# Solving for $n$.

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, exponentiation, binomial-theorem

Setup: Suppose that $n \ {\rm exp}(-n\gamma)< \tau$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}, \tau \in (0,1], \gamma >0$. How to solve for $n$?

My attempt: Let $ n\triangleq {\rm ln} \ \alpha$, then we have the following:

$$ \implies {\rm ln} \ \alpha \  {\rm exp}(-{\rm ln} \ \alpha \ \gamma) < \tau$$

$$\implies {\rm ln} \ \alpha \  {\rm exp}(\ {\rm ln} \ (\alpha^{-\gamma})) < \tau$$

$$\implies {\rm ln} \ \alpha \times \frac{1}{(\alpha)^{\gamma}} < \tau$$

$$\implies \frac{\alpha -1}{\alpha} \frac{1}{(\alpha)^{\gamma}} < \tau$$

$$\implies (1 - \frac{1}{\alpha})\frac{1}{(\alpha)^{\gamma}} < \tau$$

where the second to last inequality follows from setting $1+x$ equals to $\alpha$, and using the inequality $$\frac{x}{1+x} \leq {\rm ln} \ x$$ when $x > -1$. Can someone help me with some suggestions on how to proceed further>

Answer (score 1):

Want to solve
$f(x)
=xe^{-ax}=b,
0 < b \le 1,
a > 0
$.

$f'(x)
=e^{-ax}(1-ax)
\gt 0$
for $0 < x < 1/a$,
$=0$ for $x=1/a,
\lt 0
$
for $x > 1/a$.

Therefore $f$
has a max at
$x=1/a$
and $f(x)\to 0$
as $x \to \infty$.

At $x=1/a$,
$f(x)
=1/(ae)$
so no solution if
$b > 1/(ae)$,
one solution
($x=1/a$)
if
$b=1/(ae)$,
and two solutions if
$b < 1/(ae)$.

By writing the equation as
$-axe^{-ax}=-ab
$,
the solutions can be written
in terms of
two branches of
the Lambert W function
as $\dfrac{W(-ab)}{-a}
$.

For a numeric solution,
if you don't have the Lanbert W function handy,
start at $1/(2a)$
(for the smaller root)
or $2/a$
(for the larger root)
and apply Newton's iteration.

Playing a bit,
here are the first
Newton iterations
starting at the
suggestions above.

$g(x)
=xe^{-ax}-b,
g'(x)
=e^{-ax}(1-ax),
$.

$\begin{array}\\
g^*(x)
&=x-\dfrac{g(x)}{g'(x)}\\
&=x-\dfrac{xe^{-ax}-b}{e^{-ax}(1-ax)}\\
&=x-\dfrac{x}{1-ax}+\dfrac{b}{e^{-ax}(1-ax)}\\
&=-\dfrac{ax^2}{1-ax}+\dfrac{b}{e^{-ax}(1-ax)}\\
&=\dfrac1{1-ax}(-ax^2+\dfrac{b}{e^{-ax}})\\
g^*(c/a)
&=\dfrac1{1-c}(-c^2/a+\dfrac{b}{e^{-c}})\\
g^*(2/a)
&=\dfrac1{-1}(-4/a+\dfrac{b}{e^{-2}})\\
&=4/a-e^2b\\
g^*(1/(2a))
&=\dfrac1{1/2}(-1/(4a)+\dfrac{b}{e^{-1/2}})\\
&=-1/(2a)+be^{1/2}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This Lambert function is a new concept for me. Having taken a quick glance-- what it seems is that if I don't want numeric solution the solution for $x$ is $\frac{W(-ab)}{-a}$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Wolfram Alpha will use this function to solve your equation.